# How to search in Trello API only for not-archived cards

Tags: node.js, trello

I'm trying to create a simple Trello board search, but I got this problem, and I couldn't solve it: I get both archived & not-archived cards in my search. What parameter/something else I need to change in order to get only not-archived cards?

The URL I'm sending the request to is:

```
"https://api.trello.com/1/search?idBoards=" + TRELLO_BOARD_ID + "&key=" + TRELLO_KEY + "&modelTypes=cards&query=" + query + "&card_fields=name,idAttachmentCover,url"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through the use of the [board_fields] option on the board's endpoint. For your case, it would be `closed=false` to get Non-archived cards. It directs the API to only return cards which have not been archived.

**Source:** [Trello docs](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board#get-1-boards-board-id-cards)

Comment: But I want to use the search endpoint because I have query from the user

Comment: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/search#get-1-search Go at GET /1/Search board_fields closed